# Undefine reference error on Qt creator

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, ros

I want to use qt gui with ros. I am using ros indigo. I follow this steps.

Create qt and ros project different workspace.I organized Cmakelist.txt for creating .so file and add last 3 lines in ros project.

```makefile
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)


rosbuild_add_executable(run1 src/test.cpp)
add_library(base src/Base.cpp)
target_link_libraries(run1  base )
```

Then libbase.so file was created. I added libbase.so file to Qt project by using external library ,and ı preapered the code. when ı try to run the qt project ı have ros undifed references errors. Like this.

```
/home/anil/qt_workspace/bitirme_arayuz/../../catkin_ws/src/calisma/lib//libbase.so: undefined reference to`Node::Node(float, float, double, int, int, int, int)'
/home/anil/qt_workspace/bitirme_arayuz/../../catkin_ws/src/calisma/lib//libbase.so: undefined reference to`ros::spinOnce()'
/home/anil/qt_workspace/bitirme_arayuz/../../catkin_ws/src/calisma/lib//libbase.so: undefined reference to`ros::Rate::Rate(double)'
 /home/anil/qt_workspace/bitirme_arayuz/../../catkin_ws/src/calisma/lib//libbase.so: undefined reference to`ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'
/home/anil/qt_workspace/bitirme_arayuz/../../catkin_ws/src/calisma/lib//libbase.so: undefined reference to`ros::Rate::sleep()'
/home/anil/qt_workspace/bitirme_arayuz/../../catkin_ws/src/calisma/lib//libbase.so: undefined reference to `ros::ok()'collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [bitirme_arayuz] Error 118:14:16: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2. Error while building/deploying project bitirme_arayuz (kit: Desktop Qt 5.4.1 GCC 64bit) When executing step "Make" 18:14:16: Elapsed time: 00:06.
```

I think  when Libbase.so file occurred with the aid of target_link_libraries. There are no ROS libraries. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you added somewhere in the code the ros library (`#include <ros/ros.h>`)? If you have included it in your library (libbase.so), have you added `#include "path/libbase.h"` in your code? Also, be careful with capital letters, the linker is case sensitive.

Comment: You should switch to catkin.